# Delete Image with category Delete

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I have this function that deletes the row but does not delete the image from the folder.  I thought this would work but it doesn't.  Can someone help change this code so I can delete the image from the folder on delete?

Thanks

```
public function PermDelete($id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id);
    File::delete(public_path('images/categories/'. $category->cat_image));
    $delete = Category::onlyTrashed()->findOrFail($id)->forceDelete();
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Category has been permanently deleted successfully!');
}
```

Comment: `Category::find($id);` and `Category::onlyTrashed()->findOrFail($id)` are similar, but different enough. If that `category` row in your DB is soft deleted, `Category::find($id);` won't work. If it's not soft deleted `Category::onlyTrashed()->findOrFail($id)` won't work... You should probably try to use the same method for both... Or just do `$category->forceDelete()` instead of querying for it again.

Comment: Does this make more sense?    $delete = Category::onlyTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
    File::delete(public_path('images/categories/'. $delete->cat_image));
     $delete->forceDelete();
    return redirect()->route('all.categories')->with('success','Category information completely deleted');

Comment: Yes, this will find the `categories` row if it has been soft deleted, delete the associated file and finally force delete (hard delete) the `categories` row. As long as your intention is to only perform this for soft-deleted records, that code will work just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of use
File::delete(public_path('images/categories/'. $category->cat_image));

you can simply use the PHP function unlink to delete

```
    unlink(public_path('images/categories/'. $category->cat_image));
```

or you can debug with the below code

```
    $path = public_path('images/categories/'. $category->cat_image);

    if(\File::exists($path)){
       \File::delete($path);
    }else{
       dd('File does not exists.');
    }
```